# Архитектура master-slave. Реализация. Готовые решения

Tags: архитектура

1. Есть кэш, в котором хранится таблица с данными.
2. С этой табличкой в реальном времени взаимодействует 2-3 приложения одновременно.
3. Табличка в кэше при “холодном старте” пуста. Приложение при старте начинает долгий вычислительный процесс и заполняет таблицу.

Какие я вижу проблемы:

1. Холодный старт с двумя приложениями одновременно. Оба  запускают вычислительные процессы параллельно (или почти одновременно). Получается идет лишняя дублирующая работа.
2. Во время работы одно из копий приложения падает, перезапускается и начинает заново строить данные для таблицы. В это время в соседней копии приложения произошли какие-то изменения, которые записаны в кэш. Первое приложение перетирает новые данные своими старыми.

Я хочу реализовать что-то типа master-slave архитектуры, в которой будет только 1 копия приложения с правами rw, а остальные ro. При падении мастера права передаются кому-то другому в кластере.

Подскажите, в какую сторону «копать».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы отказался от варианта master/slave и пошел по пути, когда все инстансы равноправны. Это избавит от большого геморроя: отслеживания состояния мастера и назначения нового мастера.

Для того, чтобы разрешить обе описанных вами проблемы при использовании равноправных инстансов, нужны две вещи: лок и версия данных. Каждый результат расчет, который будет записываться в кэш, должен иметь версию. Общая схема работы следующая:

- Инстанс, который хочет пересчитать данные и записать их в кэш, должен
  сперва получить лок, а затем проверить актуальность данных.
- Если версия данных у инстанса меньше или равна версии данных в кэше,
  ничего пересчитывать не нужно.
- Если же данные в кэше устарели, делаем расчет и обновляем данные. В
  конце освобождаем лок.
- Если мы повисли на ожидании лока, значит кто-то в данные момент
  делает новый расчет и обновляет кэш. После того, как лок будет
  получен, весьма вероятно, что данные в кэше уже актуальные, и ничего
  делать не нужно.

Тогда вот что получится по описанным проблемам:

1. На старте только одно приложение возьмет лок, увидит, что данные неактуальны (т.к. их просто нет), сделает расчет и
   запишет данные. Все остальные инстансы сначала будут ждать лока, а
   потом увидят, что данные в кэше актуальные и не станут ничего
   считать.
2. Восстановившийся инстанс сперва проверит актуальность данных -- и
   поскольку другой инстанс уже успел записать в кэш свежую версию,
   никакого расчета производиться не будет.

Однако если данные обновляются довольно часто (особенно если чаще, чем время расчета), расчетов все равно будет много. В таком случае можно пожертвовать актуальностью и ввести некий интервал между обновлениями кэша. Т.о. снизится нагрузка, а интервал будет определять, насколько устаревшие данные вы позволяете использовать. Но это уже зависит от подробностей вашей задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен сервис распределенных локов и kv-хранилище, только и всего. При построении данных забираете лок, после построения данных пишете в kv-хранилище "текущая версия данных: (версия приложения)". Если одно приложение взяло лок, то другие ждут его освобождения и после получения проверяют текущую верссию кэша; если версия кэша ниже версии приложения или вовсе отсутствует, приложение перестраивает кэш. Невовремя умерший инстанс просто не успевает записать новую версию кэша, поэтому следующий инстанс перехватывает управление.

Если вы дадите больше подробностей, то можно придумать архитектуру развертывания новых версий кэша (а они так или иначе появятся и будут обратно несовместимы)